# Why is this extra bit width necessary in a multiplier?

Tags: digital-logic, adder, multiplier

In a discussion on multiplier circuits, my textbook (Brown and Vranesic's *Fundamentals of Digital Logic*, 3e) write that

> When a shifted version of the multiplicand is added to a partial product, overflow has to be avoided. Hence the new partial product must be larger by one extra bit. Figure 3.36a illustrates the process of multiplying two positive numbers. The sign-extended bits are shown in pink. Part (b) of the figure involves a negative multiplicand. Note that the resulting product has 2n bits in both cases.

I have supplied Figure 3.36 below.

I am confused about two things:

(1) Why are the pink sign extensions necessary at all (I think this has to do with the overflow discussion above but I can't quite understand why). In particular, I see no issue with simply adding \$PP_n\$ to \$M_{n+1}\$ in order to generate \$PP_{n+1}\$, while allowing \$PP_{n+1}\$ to be one bit longer than each of the inputs to that adder row so that any carry-out is stil accounted for. Why then do we still do sign extension?

(2) Why does the very first partial product have *two* bits of extension?

[image]

A very nice answer below sees to suggest that the issue is that without sign extension, the "extra bit" that I suggested keeping can be wrong. In the below, the extra 0 bit is wrong.

```
Partial product 1    101011
                   + 00000↓
                   -------
                    010101
```

One might ask why can't we just delete the extra bit if it might be wrong: after all, in the above we would get the correct 10101 output under this strategy. But of course that won't work in general (we know this on the general grounds that we need an n+1 bits to account for the addition of two n-bit numbers) and also by explicit example:

```
Partial product 1    101011
                   + 10000↓
                   -------
                    100101
```

Here ignoring the carry out of the final stage gives us the wrong answer again, 00101. Thus neither keeping nor excluding the final bit gives us the right answer *in general*. Only sign extension gives us the right answer in general.

See also my question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/692607/how-many-bits-are-needed-to-fully-capture-the-addition-of-two-integers) which I think bears on this.

Comment: I'm assuming you fully apprehend sign-extension, as an idea. Otherwise you would not even be this far. But have you taken out a piece of paper and performed this same multiplication using your own idea? I'd like to see that work, first. (Also, just a note that stopped me in my tracks, while reading. You quote this: *"sign-extended bits are shown in **blue**"* and then write *"Why are the **pink** sign extensions necessary"*... Um. What diagram with blue?)

Comment: Oof, the blue is an error (much of the rest of the book uses blue), thanks for poingting that out. Yes, I have taken out a pen and paper and done this same calculation out and it seems to work, so that's why I'm not following. I generally follow the need for sign extension when adding two numbers of different lengths (e.g. the *first* sign extension of \$PP_0\$ in the above). But once I have the two at the same length, why do I need to extend again as long as I make my result large enough (i.e. one bit longer than each of the summands)? @periblepsis

Comment: Could you please show your work? I'd rather not have to attempt a replication of what you have already done. And it would help me to more narrowly address your questions after seeing your own work. I think it would be a big help. I'd either say you were right (upon seeing it) or else be more readily able to show where it might fail, otherwise.

Comment: Sure, I will work on porting that over to the question right now. @periblepsis

Comment: @periblepsis I am having some trouble structuring the math in the tabular way shown in the figure but my "change" to the figure is so small that hopefully conveying it in words is clear: let's look at Fig 3.36b and imagine *deleting all of the pink numbers except for the single sign extension in the zeroth partial product*. The calculation seems to proceed to the very same conclusion?

Comment: it's exactly that work I didn't want to do. When I eliminate what I think you are suggesting, then I see problems. So, I'd like to see why you do NOT see problems. And the only way I can see that is if you show the work where it works for you. Because all I see is 'not good.' That may just mean I'm screwed up and can't see as well as you already do. Perhaps I'm the one who needs to be taught something. But...

Comment: Can you perhaps mention a problem you see with doing that? Perhaps I am not understanding what's going with the symbol-pushing I'm doing but what I've written out is practically the very same thing as deleting the pink (sans the first extension) as mentioned. Seeing as the deleted pink numbers are identical to the ones to their immediate right (one-to-one mapping) I also can't understand on a more general level why they're necessary? @periblepsis

Comment: And I can't see why you think they are not necessary. So I'm not sure what to say because I can't see what's inside your head that makes you think it is good. You need to retain a distinct sign bit. To me, it's that simple. I don't know how to break that down any finer. Don't you see you are shaving off a sign bit?

Comment: I understand and apologize that I can't write it out successfully @periblepsis At any rate, let me consider just forming \$PP_1\$ *under my assumption that I can delete the pink*. Then I would be  \$PP_1 = \{1,PP_0\} + \{M,0\} = 101011\$ where I've used notation for concatenation (the 1 arises because of sign extension in \$PP_0\$ and the 0 from left shift due to the multiplier \$Q\$). In this calculation I've just allowed  \$PP_1 \$ to comprise 6 bits whereas \$PP_0,M\$ comprise 5. The MSB in \$PP_1\$ is simply the carry-out of the final stage of the adder. I can't see an issue with this?

Comment: I guess I'll try words too then. (We each can use a paint program, if we wanted.) Let's zero in on (b) and the *two* bits of extension. If you limit it to just one, then you are adding "11001_" to "10010_", performing a 5-bit add producing a 5-bit result of "01011". But you do NOT want to sign extend that! (Assuming you don't have access to carry-out!) If you instead perform a 6-bit add, you need to sign extend the 2 bits for obvious reasons.  I think the text assumes you have a 6-bit add-slice but no carry out access from it. But what do I know? I don't have the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplication algorithm you show bases on multiple additions.

> (1) [...] Why then do we still do sign extension?

Adding two numbers always needs one bit more to hold the result completely. Therefore, each partial product of your examples has 6 bits.

To do this correctly with **signed** numbers, you need to sign extend each summand by one bit before the addition. You cannot simply use the carry-out bit for this.

Let's look at figure 3.36b when partial product 2 is calculated.

Correctly, with sign extension:

```
Partial product 1   1101011
                  + 000000↓
                   -------
                    110101
```

Erroneously, with carry-out:

```
Partial product 1    101011
                   + 00000↓
                   -------
                    010101
```

*(Please note that for **unsigned** numbers, you have both alternatives. You can extend by a "0" on the left of the summands, or use the carry-out. It makes no difference.)*

> (2) Why does the very first partial product have two bits of extension?

You can look at it as the result of a "hidden" addition to the initial value of zero for the least significant bit of the multiplier:

```
Multiplicand M      10010
Multiplier Q      × 01011
                  -------
Initial value      000000
                 + 110010
                 --------
Partial product 0  110010
```

The multiplicand was sign extended *before* the addition.

As adding some value to zero is trivial, you start right away with the sign extended multiplicand as partial product 0, and repeat the sign extension for the addition to partial product 1.

---

*Confirming your instinct:*

Yes, your understanding is correct.

In general you need one additional bit if you add two numbers, independent of signed or unsigned.

Therefore, we sign extend each summand by one bit before the addition. The carry out of the sum can be happily ignored, as the result always fits.

If you want to simplify your mind set, remember how to sign extend an unsigned number: You prepend a zero bit.

However, since the sum of these two zero bits and the carry out bit is simply the carry out bit, the logic for this sign extension is commonly omitted and the carry out bit is used.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very helpful and very detailed answer. I am just about ready to accept but want to confirm I understand. Underlying your answer, I think, is that my question is really a question about addition (and addition of signed numbers in particular). You claim that (1) for the addition of two n-bit unsigned numbers, *if one is interested in the full sum* then we get the correct answer is we take the carry out of the last full adder and form the corresponding (n+1)-bit value. In contrast (2) for the addition of two n-bit signed numbers, *if one is interested in the full sum*..

Comment: ...we **do not** get the correct answer is we take the carry out of the last full adder and form the corresponding (n+1)-bit value. Instead, we must sign extend the two summands to (n+1)-bit numbers, perform the addition to get an (n+1)-bit number (and we throw away the carry out here as is standard with the addition of two numbers which "fit" in the number of bits being used). Is this a correct understanding of what you've written?

Comment: If the above is correct then I suppose it means that sign extension in the unsigned case is unnecessary (even though Fig 3.62a does it) even though it still produces the right answer. Is the reason we still do that sign extension to point out that we can use multiplier units on both signed and unsigned integers (if we use the correct control logic around it), and so the multiplier unit should be arranged with sign extension since the signed case demands it?

Comment: I think much of this perhaps has to do with the author's claim (as in the OP) that "overflow has to be avoided". Is this the same thing as what we have discussed above here? Also, in your example in which the outcome is erroneous, would we arrive at the wrong answer if we simply used logic to say that the answer is acceptable under the erroneous strategy if we get no overflow? That is, in the erroneous case the XOR of the carry out of the last two stages is 0, so there is no overflow. Thus we can just delete the 0 and take 10101 which is correct? Is there a situation where this wouldn't work?

Comment: @EE18 Just try yourself the erroneous way with the example given, and look at the complete product. ;-) -- Since I cannot look into the referenced book, I cannot say anything about claims not presented here.

Comment: The "overflow" comment is in the OP :) but I understand if what I've said is convolute so no worries if it's too much to respond to. If you get the chance, perhaps just confirming my instinct on my first two replies is correct would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @EE18 I was referencing "Fig 3.62a" that I cannot see, and its surrounding text.

Comment: Oof, my mistake. I was rushing and forgot the name of the figure. I am referring to the same figure, figure 3.36! @the busybee

Answer (score 0):

The reason is quite simple.

Not regarding even signed numbers, for adding anything else than a 0 to a 5-bit number, the result will need to be a 6-bit result. Of course you don't have to extend the result beforehand, but depending on your circuitry, it might or might not make sense.

e.g. 31 + 31 = 62.

If you are doing multiplication like 15*3, for the second bit, you anyway have to shift the 5-bit number to be a 6-bit number, and for adding two 6-bit numbers, the result needs 7 bits.

e.g. 31 × 3 = 31 × 1 + 31 × 2 = 31 + 62 = 93.

If you are working with logic that multiplies two numbers together, it may make sense for the logic to do the multiplication with a loop containing shifts and adds, so anyway the registers holding the numbers need to be wide enough to contain the result.

Answer (score 0):

if you multiply an n bit number by an m bit number, in general, you have 2^n * 2^m possible outcomes.

Written in another form this is 2^(n+m) possible outcomes.

So, in general, the product must be represented in n+m bits, to uniquely identify all possible products.